# AWS can't read the credentials file

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, docker-machine

I'm deploying a Flask app using Docker Machine on AWS. The `credentials` file is located in `~/.aws/`:

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id=AKIAJ<NOT_REAL>7TUVKNORFB2A
aws_secret_access_key=M8G9Zei4B<NOT_REAL_EITHER>pcml1l7vzyedec8FkLWAYBSC7K
region=eu-west-2
```

Running it as follows:

```
docker-machine create --driver amazonec2 --amazonec2-open-port 5001 sandbox
```

According to Docker docs this should work but getting this output:

```
Error setting machine configuration from flags provided: amazonec2 driver requires AWS credentials configured with the --amazonec2-access-key and --amazonec2-secret-key options, environment variables, ~/.aws/credentials, or an instance role
```

Before you ask, yes, I set permissions in a such a way that Docker is allowed to access the credentials file.

What should I do ?

Comment: I think you need to put the file in ~/.aws/credentials then it should work.

Comment: The credentials file is located in ~/.aws/

Comment: Well the ~ is HOME of the current user. Docker maybe using another user and in his home there is no credentials file. Better use full path.

Comment: I used the details in credentials file and executed them through command line and the instance is now created and running. It's not really a solution but I got the instance running and that's what matters at the end of the day. But I still wonder why the details weren't pulled from the credentials file.

Answer (score 0):

Solution found here https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/ssh-not-available-when-creating-docker-machine-through-digitalocean

Problem was running Docker as a snap (Ubuntu's repo) instead of official build from Docker. As soon as I uninstalled the Docker snap and installed official build Docker was able to find credentials file immediately.